# getting largest and smallest number from user input

Tags: scheme, replit

hye. i'm an ultimate beginner in this language. 
i want the user to input 5 numbers, from that, it will able to get the largest/smallest number out of 5 and then display.

i am only able to do the user input. clueless on the part after that TT_TT

this is what i have so far:

```
(display "Enter first number ")
(define  n1 (read))
(newline)

(display "Please enter second number: ")
(define n2 (read))
(newline)

(display "Please enter third number: ")
(define n3 (read))
(newline)

(display "Please enter forth number: ")
(define n4 (read))
(newline)

(display "Please enter fifth number: ")
(define n5 (read))
(newline)

(define (largest n1 n2 n3 n4 n5)
   (????)
)
(largest n1 n2 n3 n4 n5)
```

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58066312/201359), and my comment is the same: take a look at the built-in procedures `min` and `max`

Comment: Try using if/then/else expressions, namely `(if <test> <then-value> <else-value>)` and comparison operators, i.e. `(< x y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in procedures `min` and `max`. But you should write your own for practice. The alternative for `max` is:

```
(define (bigger-number a b)
  (if (> a b)
      a
      b))

(define (largest . numbers)
  (define (helper current-max numbers)
    (if (null? numbers)
        current-max
        (helper (bigger-number current-max (car numbers))
                (cdr numbers))))
  (helper (car numbers)
          (cdr numbers)))
```

The `(largest . numbers)` uses the "dot-notation", so when you evaluate (for example) `(largest 1 2 3 0)`, after the function is called in the body of `largest` `numbers` will be equal to `(1 2 3 0)`.

Also we have an inner function `helper`, in `largest` so it can only be reached from inside of it, and can do all the real work of `largest`. Because of `(car numbers)` and also because of `(cdr numbers)`, `largest` will only work with at least one argument, but if you think about it `(largest)` should not make sense anyways.

Now based on that you should be able to write `smallest` on your own.